# Simple Kivy (1.11.0) example returning Black Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to Python and Kivy and am having some trouble getting started. When I run the application I only get a black screen. Advice? :)

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text = "Tupac is still alive")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Running with Python 3.7 and Kivy 1.11.0

[image: Black Screen]

Comment: works fine for me mate, try removing the requirement, maybe a version conflict?

Answer (score 0):

It works on my systems. All I did was to add:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

as the first line of your source. And it worked.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, with Python 3.6.8, and kivy 1.11.1 in a virtual environment. Hope this helps